# SQL query using Correlated joins

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have one requirement to "select all rows from fund table whose own fund_id is not found as replacement fund_id on other rows in fund table".
every fund record is having history record created with old status and new status.

whenever a particular fund is going through void process (i.e old status to new status : null-->'Issued'-->'void'--->'reissue' then a replacement fund_id is generated

linked to original record which is treated as new fund record with history as null--> 'issued'.
please see below data for more clarifications.

> FUND HISTORY TABLE:

columns and data are

> fund_hist_id        fund_id     old_status    new_status
>
> 128                2444582        null           I
>
> 127                2445579        V              R
>
> 124                2445579        I              v
>
> 123                2445579        null           I 
>            129                2445562        null           I
>
> FUND TABLE:
>
> columns and it's data are
>
> FUND_ID      FUND_NAME    ORIGINAL_FUND_ID      REPLACEMENT_FUND_ID
>
> 2444582      ABC FUND         2444582                 NULL
>
> 2445579      ABC FUND         2445579                 2444582
>
> 2445562      XYZ FUND         2445562                 NULL

PLEASE note: as per my requirement i have to select original fund ids from fund table :2445579,2445562

since  2444582 is linked as replacement fund id to any other record in fund table i have to ignore this record ,but pick 2445579 as this is the original record with 
ONE OF THE history record'null' to 'issued' .Also   2445562 is not having any replacement records linked in history as well and hence i need to select this record as

well.

Can anybody provide me query considering performance into mind.

please let me know if any of the details is not clear ?

regards
rajesh

Comment: Can anybody please provide me the query.I have prepared the query but need some inputs from my colleagues to compare if there is any better way for same ?

Answer (score 0):

considered two tables hist and fund. And required query will be:

```
select * 
from fund f, hist h
where f.FUND_ID=h.FUND_ID and f.fund_id is not null
and f.FUND_ID not in (select nvl(REPLACEMENT_FUND_ID,'0') from fund)
and h.OLD_STATUS is null and h.NEW_STATUS='I';
```